# Symfony many to many no record in db

Tags: php, symfony, collections, orm, many-to-many

I've a many to many relation with user and account. When I save the form (new user), I don't have the relation in DB. Am I something wrong ?

I read http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

```
@entity User(fosuser)
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="users")
 */
private $accounts;


/**
 * Add accounts
 *
 * @param \CM\Bundle\iNewsBundle\Entity\Account $accounts
 * @return User
 */
public function addAccount(\CM\Bundle\iNewsBundle\Entity\Account $accounts)
{
    $this->accounts[] = $accounts;

    return $this;
}




@entity Account
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="accounts")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_accounts")
 */
private $users;


/**
 * Add users
 *
 * @param \CM\Bundle\iNewsBundle\Entity\User $users
 * @return Account
 */
public function addUser(\CM\Bundle\iNewsBundle\Entity\User $users)
{
    $users->addAccount($this);
    $this->users[] = $users;

    return $this;
}
```

In DB, table users_accounts is empty. I don't see the new record.

What am I doing wrong ?

**The full userType**

```
<?php

namespace CM\Bundle\iNewsBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */

    private $roles;
    private $nbRoles;

    public function __construct($roles, $nbRoles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
        $this->nbRoles = $nbRoles;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

      $roles = $this->roles;
      $nbRoles = $this->nbRoles;

        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('userName')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                                                  'type'            => 'password',
                                                  'options'         => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                                                  'first_options'   => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                                                  'second_options'  => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                                                  'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
                                                )
            )
            ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
                                          'required' => true,
                                          'multiple' => true,
                                          'choices'  => $this->refactorRoles($roles, $nbRoles)//array("ROLE_ADMIN"=>"ADMIN", "ROLE_PUBLISHER"=>"PUBLISHER")
                                      )
            )
            ->add('accounts')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CM\Bundle\iNewsBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'cm_bundle_inewsbundle_user';
    }


    private function refactorRoles($originRoles, $nbRoles) {

      // $roles = array();

      foreach($originRoles as $key=>$item)
      {
        $roles[$key] = substr($key, 5);
      }
      // echo'<pre>';
      // var_dump($originRoles);
      // die;
      $roles = array_slice($roles, -$nbRoles, $nbRoles-1, true);
      return $roles;

    }
}
```

**The userController**

```
 public function addAction($id=null, Request $request)
    {
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->createUser();

        $roles = $this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');

        //$user->addAccount($this->get('accountManager')->getActiveAccount());



        $userForm = $this->createForm(new UserType($roles, 4), $user);
        $userForm->handleRequest($request);

        if($request->getMethod() == 'POST') 
        {
            if($userForm->isValid())
            {

                // echo'<pre>';
                // var_dump($user);
                // die;
                $userManager->updateUser($user);

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_list'));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('CMiNewsBundle:User:add.html.twig', array('userForm' => $userForm->createView()));
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us the code which uses these entities?

Comment: @frumious : I add the controller and userType. Is it enough ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your form correctly guessing the type of the `account` field?  How is it rendered?  Does the User come back from the form with the correct account set? Are there no errors?  There's a slightly confusing extra "s" on the end of the `$accounts` parameter for addAccount, but I'm sure that's irrelevant.

Comment: #frumious property account is an arrayCollection (set in user entity __construct). 
It's rendered with all items (from my db).
The user doesn't have the correct account set after creation.
It gives me no errors when saving.
The extra 's' is a mistake. I'm a beginner.

If I try to set something like ->add('accounts','collection'), it renders nothing in the account form field.

Comment: Hmm, well it sounds like Symfony has correctly guessed how to handle the account field, so that's OK.  What I meant about when it comes back from the form is: in your `addAction` code, after `$userForm->handleRequest($request)` (but before you try to persist), does $user have the account set?  Sorry if that's what you meant too!

Comment: @frumious : I found the "problem". I persist the account and it solved the problem. I thought that fosuser did it itself. Now it's work. Any idea why, I'd to do this ? Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: FOSUserBundle should definitely do that itself, see line 98 here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Doctrine/UserManager.php, no idea why it wasn't.  If persisting it yourself sorts it out, then that's great, nice one!

Comment: Have you used `updateUser()`  anywhere else successfully?

Comment: No, that's the first time that I use it. I never use FosUser before.

Comment: Hmm, well if we've got no proof that `updateUser` is working at all, and from the source code it should be essentially doing the same as what you're now doing manually, then it seems likely that there's a more general problem there.  Ask another Question if you want to get to the bottom of it, otherwise good luck with the rest of it!